# Meaning of "je vais pas en plus venir..." ?

Tags: sens, traduction

I stumbled upon the sentence:

> Déjà je suis née fille, je vais pas en plus venir parler la première.

I get the meaning of the sentence, that's not the problem. The problem is with `en plus venir`.

I could just say:

> Déjà je suis née fille, je vais pas parler la première.

I don't get `en plus venir`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I actually have no idea what the entire second part of that sentence means, even if you take out *en plus venir*. "Already I was born a girl,....I'm not going to talk the first?" WHAT? So hopefully whoever answers this explains that too.

Comment: Where did you get this sentence from ?

Comment: The omission of the *ne* (*je **ne** vais pas en plus venir*) shows it is informal spoken language. For *en plus* you can [use a dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/en%20plus). Beyond that language point, the meaning of  the sentence lies in the speaker's idea of the place of women in society.

Comment: @Aerovistae Probably spoken by a girl who believes those who say (notwithstanding the state of science in the 21 st century) that females are inferior to men: males being the leaders they speak first and show the way, and all that claptrap). I doubt the discussion belongs to FL!

Comment: @MakoDal Actually, french girl wrote that on her twitter. Thank you all.

Comment: Knowing it was posted on twitter doesn't help a lot to understand the context. Why didn't she want to talk, and where?

Comment: @jlliagre If you really want to know, it's about dating. She believes that men should talk first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Déjà je suis née fille, je vais pas en plus venir parler la première.

You could put two more comas in your sentence to make it more understandable :

> Déjà je suis née fille, je ne vais pas, en plus, venir parler la première.

In this case you can see that "en plus" mean "on top of that". 
Thought your original sentence doesn't make a lot of sense, but that's not the point.

Here is a rough translation:

> I was born a girl. I don't want to speak first on top of that.

Comment: You are missing "venir". One might translate the last part of the sentence into "I don't want to come [by] and speak first"

Comment: Missing a word doesn't mean missing a translation. In this case you have to add a "and" in your own translation that might change the meaning... Depending on the context.

Comment: "Venir parler" doesn't (only) mean "parler". There is no uncertainty about the fact there is some movement involved before the speech. You fail to convey that part of the text. The "and" conjunction doesn't change any meaning, it is simply a requirement with English where you can't say "I come speak" while French accepts "Je viens parler."

Answer (score 4):

*En plus* means furthermore here.

> Déjà je suis née fille, je vais pas en plus venir parler la première.

might be rewritten to:

> Déjà**,** je suis née fille. Je **ne** vais pas**,** en plus**,** venir parler la première.

which might be translated by:

> For a start, I was born a girl. I'm not going to take the floor first on top of that.

The first part is unusual. One would expect *Déjà, je suis une fille* unless the sentence is from a transgender person.

The second part probably means several people are going to speak on stage or something, and the person "born a girl" doesn't want to be the first one to take the floor, precisely because of being born a girl. The context should explain why (s)he thinks it is a reason not to.